# Parametric integration of curves

Tags: calculus, integration, parametric

[image: Parametric cardioid Image]

If you were to integrate this curve between $t=\pi$ and $t=\frac{5\pi}{6}$ what area would you be working out? 
Also if you integrated this curve between $t=\pi$ and $t=\frac{2\pi}{3}$ what area would you be working out?
If someone could show me a shaded diagram to show these 2 cases it would really help me. I'm a bit confused about parametric integration.

Comment: This might help: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/3.-double-integrals-and-line-integrals-in-the-plane/part-a-double-integrals/session-50-double-integrals-in-polar-coordinates/MIT18_02SC_pb_36_comb.pdf

Comment: I want to do this parametrically. I know this can be done in polar form, but that's not what i'm interested in for this particular question.I put the parametric equations at the top right of the image I posted.

Comment: You’re going to have to be more specific about what you mean by ”integrate this curve.”